# Load a page in an iframe using URL or php

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

I hope this isn't posted anywhere because it's too obvious.

On my website ([Robo Co.](http://roboserver.zapto.org)) I use two iframe elements with the names iframe_r and iframe_l.
I would like to know how to create permalinks to open pages in those iframes that are not included in the src=() element.

What I would imagine the link would be something close to: roboserver.zapto.org/main.php&iframe_r="page_to_load"&iframe_l="page_to_load"

The URL would then forward the values **iframe_r="page1"** and **iframe_l="page2"** into the imbedded php which would then load page1 into iframe_r and page2 into iframe_l.

Comment: do you want this links to work from outside your site or from within your site?
and - why the hell would you do that to yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the url scheme you used in the page

`roboserver.zapto.org/main.php&iframe_r=/left/page.php&iframe_l=/right/page.php`

you would author your iframes like so

```
<iframe id="frameLeft" src="<?= $_GET["iframe_l"] ?>"/>
<iframe id="frameRight" src="<?= $_GET["iframe_r"] ?>"/>
```

with javascript you could just

```
document.getElementById("frameLeft").src = "new url";
document.getElementById("frameRight").src = "new url";
```